# Apps Icons not appearing

Tags: applications, icon

Some of my Apps Icons are changing to a generic app icon, and I have no idea why. Tried to restart the system and nothing. 3 days ago i updated my Skype and then the icon is gone.

[image]

Comment: Have they changed everywhere (e.g. Dock, Application Switcher, etc)? Also, what version of macOS are you running?

Comment: Yes, everywhere. Im running OSx 10.12.4

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I can think of three (well, sort of) potential solutions to this. You do not need to try these in any particular order - try one first and if the issue returns, then try the other. Option 1 requires entering commands in Terminal, Option 2 doesn't but sometimes only works temporarily. And the third option is doing both Option 1 and 2.

**Option 1: Reset icon cache**

If you tried the second solution first and it doesn't work (or it only works temporarily), you can try resetting the icon cache.

- Launch Terminal (usually found in the Applications > Utilities folder)
- Enter the following commands, one at a time:

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
killall Dock
```

**Option 2: Reset and restart the Dock**

This remedy is to reset **and** restart the Dock. However, in doing so, you will need to re-add any non-default icons to your Dock. (I usually find it's a good opportunity for people to start afresh and only add things as they actually use them).

So, if your solution doesn't pan out, you can reset and restart the Dock as follows:

- Go to Finder
- Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down
- Now go to the Go menu
- Select the Library option to open the User's *Library* folder. You can let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key now.
- Go to the Preferences folder (i.e. within the Library folder)
- Find and move the **com.apple.dock.plist** file to the Trash
- Now open Terminal (usually located in Applications > Utilities)
- Enter this command `killall -KILL Dock`
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

This should resolve the issue - but remember you'll need to re-add some apps back to the Dock.

**Option 3**

You may find you need to do both options 1 and 2.

Let me know how you go.

Comment: Actually, I did first option and didnt worked. Then, I did second one and also didnt worked. After did both options I restarted my Mac and the icons came back. Thank you very much, but I cant tell exactly which worked, but after doing both and restarting mac my icons are back :). Thank you!

Comment: I did the first option only, then rebooted, seems to be fine so far!

Comment: Second Option worked perfect. OS High Sierra

Comment: Both options worked for me, OS High Sierra 10.13.3

Comment: Did option 1 on Mojave and rebooted the machine.. Works! Give this man a cookie!