# Is there a Notification Center icon cache? Trying to change Apple app icons but they change to default app icon

Tags: macos, notifications, icon

I have tried unsuccessfully to change the Apple system app icons (Mail, Messages, Reminders, etc) in LiteIcon on macOS Sierra 10.12. After applying the new icon, the Dock icon and the main icon seems to change, but the icon shown in Notifications does not (see images below).

When I finish changing the icon in Liteicon, I select the menu item: 'Clear Icon Cache and Log Out.' Also, I have tried these commands in Terminal:

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
sudo mv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store com.apple.ic
```

…and I have tried copying image content into 'Get Info' and I have tried replacing the app icon in 'APP.app'/Contents/Resources. Neither of these have worked.

Any suggestions for clearing Notification Center icon cache, or what I may do so notifications display the correct icon?

[image: notifications show like this]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to my issue using this AskDifferent post: [Apps Icons not appearing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280877/apps-icons-not-appearing).

I think what finally solved the issue was:

- deleting **~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist** and then
- Enter this command `killall -KILL Dock`
- Restart Mac

I hope this helps anyone who is having this or a similar issue. Thanks!